# How do I install additional drivers for the Intel HD3000 graphics card?

Tags: 12.04, unity, intel, 3d

I have a Samsung notebook with Intel HD3000 graphics. I have been playing with Ubuntu, messing it up and then reinstalling from scratch. But I still can't get Unity 3D to work.

At one point I think I saw a lot of "Additional Drivers" available but now I have none. How do I get the additional drivers for the HD3000 to make Unity work?

Comment: Also with this setup the way that it is, the dim settings are not working all the time, the screen will flicker like a strobe light from time to time making it really difficult to work on. :-)

Comment: Can you please identify your Samsung notebook model number?

Answer (score 1):

The HD3000 driver is built in to the kernel/Ubuntu and no separate drivers (apart from regularly updating Ubuntu) are required.

Answer (score 0):

As izx notes, the HD3000 drivers are built into the kernel.  There are no separate graphics drivers.  However, LCD backlight support is less robust.  If you are having problems with brightness and/or flicker, you could try installing packages from the ["Linux on my Samsung" PPA](http://www.voria.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1091). In particular, the `samsung-backlight` package may be helpful.